# Liberar memoria c++ (delete)

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy trabajando con Listas enlazadas (usando punteros).

En una funcion reservo memoria (usando new) siempre y cuando `Lista == NULL`
En otra funcion libero toda la memoria (con delete) y segun el enunciado del proyecto debo ser capaz de volver a generar un `nuevo_nodo`pero luego de usar delete Lista es distinto de NULL.

Lo ejemplifico con el siguiente codigo, en donde pido memoria para un primer nodo y luego para la segunda iteracion como `Lista!=NULL`libero la memoria con delete, pero para la tercera iteracion lista no es igual a null, por lo cual me pregunto si tengo que inicializar Lista a NULL luego de usar delete

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Nodo {
    int numero;
    Nodo *Siguiente;
};

int main(){
    Nodo *Lista = NULL;

    for (int i=0; i<3;i++){
        if( Lista==NULL ) {
            cout<<"\nAgregar nodo."<<endl;
            cout<<"Lista: "<<Lista<<endl;
            Lista= new Nodo;
            cout<<"Lista: "<<Lista<<endl;
        } else {
            cout<<"\nEliminar Nodo."<<endl;
            cout<<"Lista: "<<Lista<<endl;
            delete Lista;
            cout<<"Lista: "<<Lista<<endl;
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Me pregunto si manualmente tendria que inicializar Lista en NULL aun despues de haber utilizado delete, y porque sucede esto?

Comment: Creo que no te has explicado del todo bien... ¿cual es tu problema concreto? ¿Qué es lo que intentas hacer? (por favor, responde editando la pregunta)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Me pregunto si manualmente tendría que inicializarlo en NULL.

Si. Debes. Borrar un puntero no pone el puntero a valores nulos.

Como analogía imagina que el puntero es un plato y el nodo son espaguetis con boloñesa. Cuando te comes los espaguetis el plato queda sucio, puedes volver a usarlo para otro comensal (otro nodo de espaguetis) poniendo espaguetis sobre el plato sucio (el otro comensal no se va a enterar) pero si tu norma es servir sólo en platos limpios primero debes limpiarlo (poner el plato a `NULL`).

> ¿Por quée sucede esto?

Uno de los mantras de C++ es "*no pagues por lo que no usas*", que suele interpretarse como "*no hagas cosas que no sepas que son estrictamente necesarias*". El borrar el contenido de algo apuntado por un puntero y poner el puntero a `NULL` son dos operaciones, siendo la segunda innecesaria pues el puntero es usable tanto si apunta a datos borrados como si apunta a `NULL`.

Sin embargo, Bjarne Stroustrup (el creador de C++) cree que es buena idea que `delete` ponga a cero los punteros y lamenta que esta idea no se hiciera popular, he aquí un extracto de [su página web](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#delete-zero) (traducción mía):

> Consideremos
>
> ```
> delete p;
> // ...
> delete p;
> ```
>
> Si en la parte `...` no se modifica `p` el segundo `delete p;` es un error serio del que C++ no puede protegerse de manera efectiva (sin precauciones inusuales). Dado que borrar un puntero nulo es inocuo por definición, una solución simple sería que `delete p;` hiciera `p = 0;` después de hacer lo que sea que necesite. Sin embargo C++ no garantiza eso.
>
> Un motivo es que el operando de `delete` no debe ser u valor del lado izquierdo, consideremos:
>
> ```
> delete p+1;
> delete f(x);
> ```
>
> Aquí, la implementación de `delete` no tiene un puntero al que pueda asignar cero. Estos ejemplos pueden ser raros, pero hacen que no sea posible garantizar que "cualquier puntero a un objeto borrado es 0". Una manera sencilla de saltarse esta regla es tener dos punteros a un objeto:
>
> ```
> T* p = new T;
> T* q = p;
> delete p;
> delete q;   // caramba!
> ```
>
> C++ explícitamente permite que las implementaciones de `delete` pongan a cero un operando de valor izquierdo, y tenía la esperanza de que las implementaciones lo hicieran, pero esta idea no parece que se haya vuelto popular entre los implementadores.

#### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta.

- Usa `nullptr` en lugar de `NULL`: La macro `NULL` es simplemente el valor 0, esto puede llevar a confundir punteros con enteros en algunas sobrecargas, si usas el literal de puntero nulo (`nullptr`) evitarás ese posible problema.
- [Usa pre-incremento en lugar de post-incremento](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2012/04/10/leyenda-pre-y-post-incremento/).

Comment: Hola, no viene a la pregunta pero me gustaría que la pregunta tenga el cómo liberar memoria de un dinámico array de n elemento en c++(por ejemplo) char* space=new char[sub/*Sub es una variable que determina cuanto espacio debe tener la salida.*/];. Porque el titulo de la pregunta es algo general, no solo liberar espacio de un objeto, sino también de varios.

Answer (score 0):

> luego de usar delete Lista es distinto de NULL.

Sí, así es; el `operator delete` de la biblioteca estándar libera la memoria previamente asignada con `new`, y deja al puntero en un *estado inválido* (no debe usarse bajo pena de "*undefined behavior*"). Y tal como has notado, no va a asignarle `nullptr` (el NULL para punteros en C++).

Entonces, tu ejemplo podría quedar parecido a:

```
#include <iostream>
// #include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

struct Nodo {
    int numero;
    Nodo *Siguiente;
};

int main()
{
    Nodo *Lista = nullptr; // es un NULL específicO para punteros.

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        if (Lista == nullptr) {  // 
            cout << "\nAgregar nodo.\n";
            cout << "Lista: " << Lista << '\n';
            Lista = new Nodo;
            cout << "Lista: " << Lista << '\n';
        }
        else {
            cout << "\nEliminar Nodo.\n";
            cout << "Lista: " << Lista << '\n';
            delete Lista;
            cout << "Lista: " << Lista << '\n'; // ahora lo ves
            Lista = nullptr;
            cout << "Lista: " << Lista << '\n'; // ahora no lo ves
        }

    }
    //system("pause"); // disculpa, siento un rechazo 
                       // físico por esta cosa
    return 0;
}
```

(Quité también esos terribles `<< endl;`)